# Azure Devops can't find file(s) in pipeline to copy to remote machine

Tags: azure, azure-devops, file-copying

I'm struggling with a yml pipeline in Azure Devops. I've created a stage.yml, build.yml and deploy.yml file. The stage.yml is pretty forward, it has two stages and directs you to either the  build.yml or the deploy.yml.

The deploy.yml should pickup the artifact result from the build.yml and copy it with SSH to my remote environment. Azure shows the artifact as result of the first stage, so that works. However, every time I run the job it shows this message in the run output:

```
Starting: Copy JAR to host deploy
==============================================================================
Task         : Copy files over SSH
Description  : Copy files or build artifacts to a remote machine over SSH
Version      : 0.189.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh
==============================================================================
Setting up SSH service connection to remote host xx.xx.xx.xx.
Found 0 files to copy to the remote machine.
Completed copying 0 files to the remote machine.
Finishing: Copy JAR to host deploy
```

Is something missing in my configuration or is it just that the paths are misconfigured? If so, how should it be configured?

My build.yml looks like this:

```
parameters:
- name: incomingFeedName
  type: string
  default: 'project'

jobs:
- job: build_maven
  displayName: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  variables:
    - name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
      value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
    - name: MAVEN_OPTS
      value: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'

  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    # This task create cache of your all dependancies to fast the build for next time
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/caching/?view=azure-devops
    inputs:
      key: 'maven4 | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml,!**/target/**/pom.xml'
      restoreKeys: |
        maven4 | "$(Agent.OS)"
        maven4
      path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
    displayName: 'Cache local maven repo'

  - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    # This task will authenticate your maven feed for input dependancies and output dependancies
    inputs:
      artifactsFeeds: ${{parameters.incomingFeedName}}
    displayName: 'Authenticate to Azure Maven feed'

  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
      mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
      goals: 'deploy'
    displayName: 'Maven build'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    # pick up the results of the build (JAR file) and stage them.
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target'
      Contents: '*.jar'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    displayName: Stage Jar files for publishing

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    # Upload the results into the pipeline. This files can be used in the release pipeline
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'Binaries'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
    displayName: Publish Jar file
```

And the deploy.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: envName
  type: string

jobs:
- deployment: deploy_jar
  displayName: Deploy JAR
  environment: ${{ parameters.envName }}
  variables:
 # - group: 'global'
  - name: 'endpoint'
    ${{ if eq(parameters.envName, 'Test') }}:
      value: 'deploy'
 # pool:
  #  name: 'poolname here'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
          # - task: DeleteFiles@1
          #   inputs:
          #     sourceFolder: '${Pipeline.Workspace)\Binaries'
          #     contents: '*'
          #     removeSourceFolder: true
          #   displayName: 'Clear JAR file from pipeline downloads: Before'
          # - download: current
          #   artifact: Binaries

          - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
            inputs:
              sshEndpoint: ${{variables.endpoint}}
              sourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              # contents: '*'
              targetFolder: '~/_work/'
              readyTimeout: '20000'
              # overWrite: true
            displayName: 'Copy JAR to host ${{variables.endpoint}}'

          # - task: SSH@0
          #   inputs:
          #     sshEndpoint: ${{variables.endpoint}}
          #     runOptions: 'commands'
          #     commands: 'execute service'
          #     readyTimeout: '200'
          #   displayName: 'Run service'

          # - task: DeleteFiles@1
          #   inputs:
          #     sourceFolder: '${Pipeline.Workspace)\Binaries'
          #     contents: '*'
          #     removeSourceFolder: true
          #   displayName: 'Clear JAR file from pipeline downloads: After'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At deploy time, your build artifact will be downloaded to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`. `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` won't be valid here.

You can verify this by adding a step like this before your copy:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
    Write-Host "Pipeline.Workspace is $(Pipeline.Workspace)"
    Get-ChildItem $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    Get-ChildItem $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```